# Unity Firebase Security

Tags: unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am developing an app on unity3d and using firebase realtime database for user info and stats. The users need to authorize (via google) to read/write data to database inside the app. Since, users do not know the database address, which is embedded inside the app, do I still have security problem? If yes, what should I do? I do not want any user to change their own stats :)

Comment: What do you mean by "database address embedded inside the app"?

Comment: the user can see only the app interface, since the database is configured in unity code (i.e. C#), user can not see the web address of the firebase database (i.e. https://INSTANCE-XYZAB.firebaseio.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you still might have a security problem. Security by obscurity is not true security. It is still possible for people to snoop network traffic away from your app to get the address of the database. The firebase way of solving this is via [Database Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) configured in the console/CLI. Making it so users cannot change their own stats will depend on how your app is structured and who IS allowed to change them. In any case, this can be expressed in Rules as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I also add a validation step, is it still the case? for example, for the new data, if add another child data which will be a function of critical data to secure, i can avoid unintended write operations? the function will be obscured inside the app... Am I right?

Comment: Simple Example: Child data "balance" = 10; Child data "val" = 2*balance = 20. In write validation, I can configure the rule to check whether val == 2*balance. since user can not know the function to calculate "val", he cannot change the "balance" value?

Comment: What you're describing sounds like the correct use of the Database Rules. I'm not sure what you mean by "The function will be obscured inside the app". If it exists in the code deployed to users then it probably isn't totally secure.

Answer (score 0):

Just you have accessibility to database and its rules. Users just can read and write and change their data and they can't change another one's data.